# Checking if a string value is holding null or not inside a loop and then parsing it

Tags: c#, null, nullable

I am fetching some data then looping it in the below way.

```
foreach(string str in result)
{
string[] s = str.split('|');
User us = new User(); 
us.Code = int.parse(s[0]);
us.TempId = int.parse(s[1]);
us.TargetId = int.parse(s[2]);
us.StreetId = int.parse(s[3]);
Collection.Add(us);
}
```

The `Code`, `TempId`, `TargetId`, `StreetId` are nullable, in my result i may get NULL values as well so the `int.parse()` is throwing error when there is null.

If the value is null then i need to assign null value, if not null then parse it to integer

How do i handle this in an efficient way ?

Comment: Use `int.tryParse`

Comment: `us.Code = int.TryParse(s[0], out int num) ? num : null;` etc...

Comment: There is no `parse` method available on `int`. There is a `Parse` method...

Comment: String.Split doesn't return null in the splitted array. Empty strings yes but not null strings

Comment: Try `s[0] == String.Empty ? null : int.Parse(s[0]);` which could be an extension method: `public static int? ParseEmptyAsNull(this string s) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : int.Parse(s);`

Comment: @NetMage not sure you can do that with a ternary. Perhaps it requires newer versions of C#?

Comment: @Steve Target typing for ternary operator was added in C# 9, otherwise `(int?)null` would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int.TryParse` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

```
...
if (int.TryParse(s[0], out int code) us.Code = code; else us.Code = null;
```

Comment: A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter...

Comment: @HereticMonkey What out or ref parameter are you referring to?

Comment: The one in [the previous revision of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66035345/1), @NetMage.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (s[1] == null) {
   us.TempId = null;
} else {
   us.TempId = int.Parse(s[1]);
}
```

or transform it with ternary operator

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't compile in my compiler...

Comment: it`s only approach - if it doesn't compile try to fix. but main idea will be the same - check value for null - then set value to property null or not null value. Sorry have no ide on current pc

Comment: Seems kind of mean to tell someone to try something that doesn't compile...

Comment: please at least sometimes try to write some code with very simple logic without copy and paste - extremely useful. Good luck

Comment: I do it all the time. But not as an answer on Stack Overflow. When answering on Stack Overflow, I make sure my code works before posting. I think that's the least I can do when offering an answer. Apparently you do not. Good luck.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Typos happen.